# random number generation

Tags: assembly, random, 68000

How to generate random numbers using assembly code in the range 1--4    ?

Comment: this is going to be different for each architecture you want to target. Are you using ARM? x86?

Comment: I m using for EyeBot, and need coding for further work

Comment: The EyeBot apparently uses a 68000 CPU - I've added an appropriate tag to help you get a CPU-specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what system you are trying to do this on, so here is a general answer, that should apply, no matter which:

```
query the system time, using whatever syscall / library call / api you have available
and out the top bits, leaving only the lowest 2
```

tadaa. randum numbers.

if you want them more random use perhaps do this instead:

```
query the system time
and out the top bits leaving only the lowest 4 store in "register1"
Loop:
       do something unimportant
       do something else unimportant
       etc.
       count down register1
       jump to EndLoop if register1==0
       jump Loop
EndLoop:
query the system time
and out the top bits, leaving just the lower two
```

Cheers!

/B2S

EDIT: Sorry, been on holiday out of internet's reach. (yes, genuinely amazing that such places still exist) I'm not particularly familiar with either EyeBot nor 68k asm. So I don't know the syscall to read in the clock or time (either will do). So look that one up, the rest of the code should be something like

```
//Assuming you have called the syscall to get the system time/clock, and stored it in D0
      AND #%01111, D0
loop: 
     // It really doesn't matter,
     // What Instructions you put here,
     // just put 4 or 5 instructions that don't
     // mess with D0, eg. AND, MOVE, ADD, AND, OR

      SUB #1, D0

      TST D0  // TST instruction is probably not needed
      BEQ EndLoop
      JMP loop
EndLoop:
//      Get the system time/clock again (Next instruction assumes clock is in D0)
      AND #%011, D0
```

D0 should now contain your random number

Comment: What will be the code?
loop: MOVE.L D0
MOVE.L D0%4, D1
ADD.L #1, D1
CMP.L D1<4
MOVE.L D1, D2
JMP loop
...........
.....??  correct?

Answer (score 3):

1 + (rand() % 4), in general (where rand() is a decent random integer generator).

```
call [_rand]
mod eax, 4 ; or 'and eax, 3' - same thing
inc eax
```

You could go read up on say [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), for how to implement rand(), but it's pretty complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do own **quasi** random number generator.
If you have access to the RTC (real clock counter) or CPU time stamp than you can do rutine relatively simple.

Very simple example:

```
Int LastIteration;
Int IterationCounter;

...


++IterationCounter;
LastIteration = CpuTimeStamp + IterationCounter;
RndNum = LastIteration & 3 + 1;
```

This quasi rnd generator is enough unpredictable if you don't need a lot of generated numbers per second.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple technique to get somewhat a "random" number (it's not really random though), if the API doesn't provide one

1. variable time = get the system time
2. variable remainder = time % 4
3. variable randomNumber = time + 1

You can use this with every language (provided that you can access the time).

For an advanced random number generator in 68K, you can see [this link](http://members.multimania.co.uk/leeedavison/68k/prng/index.html).